# Using tcpdump to watch which websites are accessed on my network

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, http-get, tcpdump

I've just got my hands on a Raspberry Pi and I've set it up to act as the DNS and DHCP server on my home network.  This means that all network requests go through it before they are released into the wild...  Which offers me a great opportunity to use tcpdump and see what is happening on my network!

I am playing around with the tcpdump arguments to create the perfect network spy.  The idea is to capture HTTP GET requests.

This is what I have so far and it's pretty good:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0)>> 2):4] = 0x47455420' -A
```

- The `-i eth0` tells it which interface to listen to
- The bit in quotes is a nifty bit of hex matching to detect a GET request
- The `-A` means "print the ASCII contents of this packet"

This fires every time anything on my network sends a GET request, which is great.  My question, finally, is how can I filter out boring requests like images, JavaScript, favicons etc?

Is this even possible with tcpdump or do I need to move onto something more comprehensive like tshark?

Thanks for any help!

DISCLAIMER: Currently the only person on my network is me... This is not malicious, it's a technical challenge!

Comment: Have you also set it up as a proxy / NAT / router? A DNS/DHCP only server won't see HTTP traffic.

Comment: Yes, this won't see the contents of traffic to/from other machines on any switched (which is to say remotely modern) local network.  And it will only see DNS queries which actually hit it - not those that are resolved from a client's DNS cache, or from a client explicitly configured to use an external DNS server instead.  To get everything, generally you have to capture on the gateway or (if used) NAT box - often one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

Grep is your friend :-) `tcpdump ... | grep -vE "^GET +(/.*\.js)|(/favicon.ico)|(.*\.png)|(.*\.jpg)|(.*\.gif)|... +HTTP` will hide things like `GET /blah/blah/blah.js HTTP 1/.0`, `GET /favicon.ico HTTP 1/.0`, `GET /blah/blah/blah.png HTTP 1/.0`, *etc*.